# Python csv writer automatically round time

Tags: python, csv

I want to write time(like 1:34.12) into a csv using csv.writer
But the csv will show 1:34.1. How to show exactly 1:34.12?

If I turn 1:34.12 to 1.34.12 , the csv can show 1.34.12

```
import csv

with open("combine.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-8-sig") as new_file

    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
    time = "1:34.12"
    list = [time, others]
    csv_writer.writerow(list)
```

Comment: How do u want the time to be rounded.

Comment: I don't see how this code can produce those results.  How are you viewing the csv file after it's created?  Perhaps your viewing program is setting the column width to six characters, so it _appears_ to be truncated?  Try looking at the csv in a plain text editor.

Answer (score 1):

That code will write 1:34:12 to the new line.

You can confirm this by using:

```
cat combine.csv # Linux/Mac
type combine.csv # for windows
```

I believe the issue is with your viewer.  IE if you are using Microsoft Excel it will round this by default.

You can change the cell property (right click cell property) and use this type: mm:ss.00